# How to avoid from multipe renders in a single react native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my home screen, here in useEffect I am calling functions. All functions behind the scene return some response from some API's, so my home screen renders 6 times. Please suggest to me how to avoid this behavior.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCities());
    dispatch(getHotels());
    dispatch(getRooms());
    dispatch(getNews());
    dispatch(getDeals());
    dispatch(getDestinations());
}, []);
```

Comment: Assuming all those functions return a promise, wait for all of them to be resolved by using Promise.all, then show the data.

Comment: You can create a single action that calls these APIs and when all APIs have been returned you can update the store. You could use redux-thunk as middleware.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal thanks for your suggestion, but if single action fails due to some reason then all functions will be brake down, so in this scenario is this good to use this  approach to create a single action

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component with *memo* (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).
This will generate a memorized version of your component that will mount again only if some of its props change the value. If your six functions calls don't change the preview props values the component will not cause a re-render.